# ADD ID and Value to CheckBox in jqxListBox({})

Tags: jquery, jqwidget

I need to Add ID to CheckBoxes in List Box

```
<input type=”checkbox” name=”vehicle” id = 1>Code</br>
<input type=”checkbox” name=”vehicle” id = 2>Select
```

once I select the CheckBox and I need to Get the CheckBox Id and I can also tick the CheckBox Based on ID how to Do????

But Here Cannot Add That

```
var source = [
"Affogato",
"Caffé Latte"];

// Create a jqxListBox
$(“#jqxListBox”).jqxListBox({
source: source,
theme: ‘energyblue’,
width: ’200px’,
height: ’250px’,
checkboxes:true
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxlistbox/index.htm?(arctic)#demos/jqxlistbox/checkboxes.htm

You can use the `checkChange` event and in your case the source should have two values (1 - displayMember, 2 - valueMember):

```
var source = [{
  vehicle: "Affogato",
  id: 122
}, {
  vehicle: "Americano",
  id: 156
}, {
  vehicle: "Bicerin",
  id: 1023
}, {
  vehicle: "Breve",
  id: 4567
}];

$("#jqxListBox").jqxListBox({
  source: source,
  displayMember: "vehicle", 
  valueMember: "id",
  checkboxes: true
});

$("#jqxListBox").on('checkChange', function (event) {
  var args = event.args;
  // get new check state.
  var checked = args.checked;
  // get the item and it's label and value fields.
  var item = args.item;
  var itemLabel = item.label;
  var itemValue = item.value;
});
```

Try this to help: https://jsfiddle.net/charlesrv/YnqPP/31/

Comment: But this is not the answer i want i have a jqListBox i cannot add the ID to this. This has a there auto incrementing number. but it is useless for me.

Comment: So to that point, I mean why the need of an ID? (and if notice each listbox item has a numeric ID like listitem[number][listbox_name])

Comment: But here there are diffrent kind of ID not 1,2,3, they are unique from each other

Comment: Well they start at 0, and then 1,2,3... Maybe you can tell me what you're trying to do? (the reason why you need those IDs)

Comment: I don't need 0,12,3 I have some IDs Like 122,156,1023,4567, like this once i click the check box i need those values. but i cannot enter the ID only Discription

Comment: So in that case just need to ad that ID as `valueMember` and keep the other value as `displayMember`